# Ubuntu Server NAS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raid

I am using a ubuntu server to create a Raid 5 NAS. The motherboard I have is Gigabyte 78lmt which has 6 sata 2 ports. I have an array of 5 WD NAS Drives and one SSD from where I boot the server. I am confused whether I should spend on getting a new motherboard since I dont know if Sata2 ports will affect my performance vs on Sata3 I should be able to get a good throughput. I thought its better to ask pros here before spending money one a new motherboard. Also which motherboard would you guys recommend if my plan is to scale for more storage in future. Thanks!

Comment: Hardware recommendations are off-topic on Super User. So all that remains is your question „Does SATA2 affect my performance?“. To answer that, additional information is required: Do you have an additional network card installed?

Comment: Yes! I have a additional quad port gigabit ethernet card installed. I was planning on creating a link aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

WD Red NAS drives typically have a bandwidth of 6 Gb/s, while SATA2 is only 3Gb/s. However, as Daniel B pointed out, if you are using a single gigabit network uplink, that will be your performance bottleneck, not the SATA bus. If you added an additional NIC and have multiple gigabit connections that will be hitting the array at once, then it may cause problems, but only beyond 3 gigabit.